# Sometimes I can't pass through the login screen, mouse moves but can't click on anything

Tags: display, mouse, login

thank you in advance for the attention.

I've fixed my PC just a week ago, the guy even installed me windows 10 and everything. It all works great, startup is super fast, everything goes perfectly.

However, this is the second time that this has happened- sometimes I go out for an hour or two and when I come back and want to re-access my computer, I can't pass through the login screen. I tried to take a screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECymv.jpg

This is what I get, except that instead of having these icons on the right hand corner of the screen, I have the icons in the following image:

[image]

The problem is that I can't pass through this screen. I can move my mouse fine. But usually, when I click on my mouse, a new page pops up which says "toshiba" and below it says "Sign in", exactly like in the above image, with the drawing of the little man. But when I click on my mouse, nothing happens. So, I try to suspend my computer, but when I turn it on again, the same situation occours.

The only way out of this is to reboot my computer, but then I have to lose what I was typing in word. It even says "If you reboot now, you may lose data" and I have to bite the bullet... After rebooting, all works just fine again.

I can also click on the other two icons, that open up a page about internet connections or something like that.

This has only happened twice so far. Any way to fix this issue? It's very annoying. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**What Apparently Worked**

*The Escape Key*

"As one thought, I know that (anecdotally) it sometimes seems  I have to press the ESC key (perhaps more than once) when logging in to Windows 10 to type my password or to otherwise make things responsive."

---

**Original Answer**

> I tried to take a screenshot [...] This is what I get, except that instead of having these icons on the right hand corner of the screen, I have the icons in the following image[.]

Perhaps I am misreading this, but if you are using the [Windows 10 Login Background Changer](https://github.com/Krutonium/Windows-10-Login-Background-Changer) program (which is what is partially displayed in the second screenshot), you may want to discontinue using it.

As a quick history, according to this [Lifehacker article from 2015](https://lifehacker.com/this-utility-can-change-your-windows-10-login-image-1721713560), older versions of Windows 10 did not allow you to select a custom image as a Login background. So it seems that this program was intended to allow you to, say, use your first image as both your Lock screen (with the time) and the background for your Sign-in screen (your Login screen).

However, the current GitHub page indicates that with Insider Preview Build 14279+ and the normal Anniversary Update (Windows 10 Version 1607, released in late 2016), this program has been rendered "obsolete". With the listed Windows versions or later, Microsoft now allows this behavior without third-party software.

In any case, it could be (at a guess) interfering with your login attempts. At the time of this answer, under its last [two releases](https://github.com/Krutonium/Windows-10-Login-Background-Changer/releases), it specifically notes that they attempt to fix "Can't Login" and "UI Start" issues respectively (with the former sounding very pertinent to your complaint).

---

*Note that if you do update your version of Windows to an appropriate version, this [How-To Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/223875/how-to-change-the-login-screen-background-on-windows-10/) shows how to use the same background on your Lock screen and Sign-in screens.*

---

Comment: Hey friend! Thanks for the response, I didn't see it until now. Sorry if I wrote this in a bad way, but I meant to only put in that picture as an example, because I couldn't take a screenshot of the actual screen that I had. I don't use that program!

Comment: You're welcome and my apologies. About the question, it's fine, I was making a bad assumption apparently. As one other thought, I know that sometimes it seems (anecdotally) I have had to press the ESC key, sometimes more than once, as well when logging in to Windows 10 to type my password or get things to become responsive. Unfortunately, other than that, I am not sure what else might help. Regardless, I sincerely hope you get your issue solved.

Comment: Dude, I think that you fixed the issue!! It's all about that esc key. Thanks for the help man :D

Comment: Lol sometimes it's the simple things! For what it's worth, glad to hear it & you're welcome. =)